# How exactly the midpoint of the object is selected in YOLO algorithm?

Tags: object-detection, yolo

The boundaries of the object are encoded into 4 scalars: Bx, By, Bh, Bw. Bh and Bw are calculated using the ratio of the width of the bounding box to the width of the relative grid cell. But I can't find any explanation on how exactly the coordinates Bx and By of the mid-point are selected?

[image: Midpoint of the object detected]

Answer (score 0):

As far as midpoint is considered, you already **know** it as it is given in the training dataset(or can be calculated from the **labelled** rectangle coordinates).

About calculating Bx and By from midpoint(let's say p,q):

A single grid block size: (m,m)

Bx = (p - m*floor(p/m))/m ,similar for By.
[floor being the integer part of a decimal number]

Hope this helps...